# Postgresql Partition - Funtion calling in Select Query - is slow

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, database-partitioning

Our system is a SAAS based system we use ClientID as a Masking for data fetching.
The DB load is based on the Size of the Company. So we partitioned the DB based on ClientID

**Example: Before Partition**

### clienttable

| clientid | clientname | clientaddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ... |
| 2 | EMN | ... |
| 3 | XYZ | ... |

### employeetable

| clientid | employeeid | employeename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | AAA |
| 1 | 124 | BBB |
| 2 | 125 | CCC |
| 2 | 126 | DDD |
| 3 | 127 | EEEE |

### jobtable

| clientid | jobid | jobname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | YTR |
| 1 | 235 | DER |
| 2 | 236 | SWE |
| 3 | 237 | VFT |
| 3 | 238 | GHJ |

### *Example: After Partition*

**clienttable**

| clientid | clientname | clientaddress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ... |
| 2 | EMN | ... |
| 3 | XYZ | ... |

### employeetable

**employeetable_1**

| clientid | employeeid | employeename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | AAA |
| 1 | 124 | BBB |

**employeetable_2**

| clientid | employeeid | employeename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 125 | CCC |
| 2 | 126 | DDD |

**employeetable_3**

| clientid | employeeid | employeename |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 127 | EEE |

### **jobtable**

**jobtable_1**

| clientid | jobid | jobname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 234 | YTR |
| 1 | 235 | DER |

**jobtable_2**

| clientid | jobid | jobname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 236 | SWE |

**jobtable_3**

| clientid | jobid | jobname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 237 | VFT |
| 3 | 238 | GHJ |

**When we write select queries:**

`Select employeeid,employeename from employeetable where clientid=2;`

This query runs faster after partition. The problem we face is we have some user defined function to manipulate some data.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_JOB_COUNT(NUMERIC, NUMERIC) RETURNS NUMERIC AS $BODY$
   DECLARE
    p_client_id             ALIAS FOR $1;
    p_employee_id       ALIAS FOR $2;
    v_is_count      NUMERIC := 0;
   BEGIN  

    SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) INTO v_is_count FROM JOBTABLE where CLIENTID=p_client_id AND CREATEDBY=p_employee_id;
        RETURN v_is_count;
   
   END; $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

`Select employeeid,employeename,GET_JOB_COUNT(2,employeeid) from employeetable where clientid=2;`

This query is slow after partition. Does this means the GET_JOB_COUNT function is run across Partition?

Is that the problem, then we can't use Functions like this in Select query after partition?

Comment: The function will be called once for **each row** (for all rows that are selected with `clientid = 2`

Comment: How exactly did you partition the table? And which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: we use PostgreSQL 13.4 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu

Comment: We partitioned based on "ClientID" see the "After Partition Section" in the Question

Comment: What are the types of the columns?  If you are comparing ints to numeric, that could inhibit partition pruning.

Answer (score 0):

The function will be called once for each and every row from the employeetable (that is selected through the WHERE clause). I doubt you can improve the performance in any significant way using that approach.

It's better to do the aggregation (=count) for all rows at once, rather than for each row separately:

```
select e.employeeid, employeename, t.cnt 
from employeetable e 
  left join (
    select clientid, createdby, count(job_id) as cnt 
    from jobtable 
    group by client_id, created_by
  ) j on j.clientid = e.clientid and j.createdby = e.employeeid 
where e.clientid = 2;
```

Another option to try is to use a lateral join to eliminate rows from the jobtable early - I am not sure if the optimizer is smart enough for that in the query above. So you can try this as an alternative:

```
select e.employeeid, employeename, j.cnt 
from employeetable e 
  left join lateral (
    select count(jt.job_id) as cnt 
    from jobtable jt 
    where jt.clientid = e.clientid
      and jtcreatedby = e.employeeid
  ) j on true 
where e.clientid = 2;
```

---

If you really do want to stick with the function, maybe making it a SQL function helps the optimizer. It at least removes the overhead of calling PL/pgSQL code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_job_count(p_client_id numeric, p_employee_id numeric) 
  returns bigint 
as 
$body$
  SELECT COUNT(JOB_ID) 
  FROM JOBTABLE 
  where CLIENTID = p_client_id 
    AND CREATEDBY = p_employee_id;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
stable
parallel safe;
```

But I doubt that you will see a substantial improve by that.

As a side not: using `numeric` for an "ID" column seems like a rather strange choice. Why aren't you using `int` or `bigint` for that?

Comment: The PLSQL count function given here is just an example, we have complex manipulation done inside the function which we are not able to solve as left outer join/ subquery/ SQL function. Anyways from your answer, we infer that function call is select query will be run for every row for the selected rows and not on every partition, Thank you.

Comment: @RSK: if you want to run the function per partition, you need to make it a set returning function passing the partition key to it, then you can join to the output of the function